# Need clarification about array syntax

Tags: c++, arrays

What is the difference between declaring a 2D array in C++ like this:

```
int mp[3][3]={{0,2,1},
              {0,2,1},
              {1,2,0}};
```

And this?

```
int mp[3][3]={0,2,1,
              0,2,1,
              1,2,0};
```

Is the above an array where all 3 elements are arrays themselves while the bottom one is an array of non-array elements or are both read by the compiler as the same?

Comment: What language? Some handle it differently.

Comment: @A--C in C++. I edited to add that I need to understand it in C++

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They're equivalent. The first one is a completely braced form. When the interpretation is unambiguous (such as in the second form), the standard allows eliding the braces.

Comment: I ask because my program was giving me different results. I'm guessing I changed something else and forgot about it.

Comment: @Chase what is your compiler?

Comment: @Grijesh Chauhan Microsoft Visual Studio C++ 2010 Express

Comment: As per [dcl.init.aggr]§10, they should be equivalent. §11 even has an example matching your case almost exactly.

Comment: @Angew Before I forget, thank you. I was able to find the real problem with my program after you clarified this for me.

Answer (score 1):

Both are same you can access elements for matrix using following loop:

```
for (i=0;i<3;i++)   
     for(j=0;j<3;j++)     
        printf("%d ",mp[i][j] );
```

One difference in when you give braces in first case then first argument can be omitted like:

```
int mp[][3]={{0,2,1},
              {0,2,1},
              {1,2,0}};
```

But C++ compiler will give you **warning:** missing braces around **for second type of declaration.**

**EDIT:**
As you commented:  my program was giving me different results

I have written a code. working fine on C++ (gcc-4.7.2). [Check here](http://ideone.com/IvWgzL)

Comment: Um, **some** C++ compilers (and, I assume, **some** C compilers) will give a warning.